# How to split image of table at vertical lines into three images?

Tags: opencv

I want to split an image of a table at the vertical lines into three images as shown below. Is it possible? The width of each column is variable. And the sad thing is that the left vertical line is drawn down from the header as you can see.

- Input image (input.png)

[image]

- Output image (output1.png)

[image]

- Output image (output2.png)

[image]

- Output image (output3.png)

[image]

---

Update 1

> And the sad thing is that the left vertical line is drawn down from the header as you can see.

It means I guess the following image B is easier to split. But my case is A.

[image]

---

Update 2

I am trying to do the way @HansHirse gave me. My expectation is sub_image_1.png, sub_image_2.png and sub_image_3.png are stored in the out folder. But no luck so far. I'm looking into it.

https://github.com/zono/ocr/blob/16fd0ec9a2c7d2e26279ec53947fe7fbab9f526d/src/opencv.py

```
$ git clone https://github.com/zono/ocr.git
$ cd ocr
$ git checkout 16fd0ec9a2c7d2e26279ec53947fe7fbab9f526d
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec -it ocr /bin/bash
$ python3 opencv.py
```

Comment: Sorry but I couldnt understand "the sad thing is that the left vertical line is drawn down from the header" this part. The other lines also like that ?

Comment: @Yunus Temurlenk Hi, I updated the question.

Comment: It's okay! there is a function which will still find your lines.

Comment: @zono Regarding your "Update 2": Is the `out` folder present? `cv2.imwrite` expects all (sub)folders to be existing, and won't create any. Also, I had a look at your image source. Maybe lower the `thr_x` threshold, since you have some quite "thin" columns in your tables.

Comment: @HansHirse Oh. I replaced to 'out/sub_image_' instead of '/out/sub_image_'.

Comment: And I'm checking around `thr_x`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your table is perfectly aligned, you can inverse binary threshold your image, and count (white) pixels along the y-axis to detect the vertical lines:

[image: Count white pixels along y-axis]

You'll need to clean the peaks, since you might get plateaus for the thicker lines.

That'd be my idea in Python OpenCV:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io              # Only needed for web reading images

# Web read image via scikit-image; convert to OpenCV's BGR color ordering
img = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTqBs.png'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Inverse binary threshold grayscale version of image
img_thr = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Count pixels along the y-axis, find peaks
thr_y = 200
y_sum = np.count_nonzero(img_thr, axis=0)
peaks = np.where(y_sum > thr_y)[0]

# Clean peaks
thr_x = 50
temp = np.diff(peaks).squeeze()
idx = np.where(temp > thr_x)[0]
peaks = np.concatenate(([0], peaks[idx+1]), axis=0) + 1

# Save sub-images
for i in np.arange(peaks.shape[0] - 1):
    cv2.imwrite('sub_image_' + str(i) + '.png', img[:, peaks[i]:peaks[i+1]])
```

I get the following three images:

[image: Sub image 1]

[image: Sub image 2]

[image: Sub image 3]

As you can see, you might want to modify the selection by +/- 1 pixel, if an actual line is only 1 pixel wide.

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm now trying to implement it on  my environment. Will let you know the result.

Comment: It worked. My python code was wrong. Thanks for your great answer!

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has a line detection function:

You can filter the lines that are returned by passing `min_theta` and `max_theta`. For vertical lines you can specify maybe : `88` and `92` respectively for margin.

This is a edited sample taken from openCV documentation:

```py
import sys
import math
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
def main(argv):

    default_file = 'img.png'
    filename = argv[0] if len(argv) > 0 else default_file
    # Loads an image
    src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(filename), cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    #some preparation of the photo
    dst = cv.Canny(src, 50, 200, None, 3)

    # Copy edges to the images that will display the results in BGR
    cdst = cv.cvtColor(dst, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cdstP = np.copy(cdst)

    lines = cv.HoughLines(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 150, None, 88, 92) #min and max theta
```

You can get the x, y coordinate of the line and draw them by using the following code.

```py
    if lines is not None:
        for i in range(0, len(lines)):
            rho = lines[i][0][0]
            theta = lines[i][0][2]
            a = math.cos(theta)
            b = math.sin(theta)
            x0 = a * rho
            y0 = b * rho
            pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000*(-b)), int(y0 + 1000*(a)))
            pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000*(-b)), int(y0 - 1000*(a)))
            cv.line(cdst, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)
```

Alternatively you can also use `HoughLinesP` as this allows you to specify a minimum length, which will help your filtering. Also the lines are returned as x,y pairs for each end making it easier to work with.

```py
    linesP = cv.HoughLinesP(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 50, 10)

    if linesP is not None:
        for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
            l = linesP[i][0]
            cv.line(cdstP, (l[0], l[2]), (l[2], l[3]), (0,0,255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)

    cv.imshow("Source", src)
    cv.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Standard Hough Line Transform", cdst)
    cv.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Probabilistic Line Transform", cdstP)

    cv.waitKey()
    return 0
```

[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb)

To crop your image you can take the x coordinates of the lines you detected and use numpy slicing.

```py
for i in range(0, len(linesP) - 1):
            l = linesP[i][0]
            xcoords = l[0], linesP[i+1][0][0]
            slice = img[:xcoords[0],xcoords[1]]
            cv.imshow('slice', slice)
            cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: after you obtain the line you can use numpy slicing to split the array

Comment: Thanks! Please give me some time to try it.