# Python - Identify Table Header from scanned image and enhance it

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am new to computer vision area and was exploring various tutorials related to identification of tables in Python using OpenCV

Below is my code I got by referring several websites. Able to identify the table and cells almost perfectly. But my input image has darkened table header and I want to make it as white background to make the table header's content much clear

Not sure how to proceed further after identifying the tables and cells using OpenCV.

**Code Snippet :**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

table_image_contour = cv2.imread("table1.jpg", 0)

table_image = cv2.imread("table1.jpg")

ret, thresh_value = cv2.threshold(table_image_contour, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
dilated_value = cv2.dilate(thresh_value,kernel,iterations = 1)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_value,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
 x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
 if y< 1000:
     cv2.rectangle(table_image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),1)

plt.imshow(table_image)
```

**Input Image :**
[image: Input table]

**Output Image :**
[image: Output table]

**Expectation :**
As can be seen from the above output image I want to make the table header clean and neat looking by removing the darkened background thereby revealing the text properly

Also by any chance can the table border and cell border can be drawn with black colour instead of red / blue colour from OpenCV ?

Comment: One solution is to label a cell as header if it has average/median color less than the average of all the cells. Then change that color to whatever you want.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200291/remove-blackened-section-of-image-using-python-opencv/60218663#60218663

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for prompt response. Could you please explain with a code snippet. Apologies I am completely new to OpenCV and have no idea on how to change the color of cell

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for pointing out. That's close to what I want but the solution provided there won't work for all the images. Also by any chance can the border of the table be drawn with black color instead of default red / blue colour of OpenCV ?