# How to remove spotted background from numbers using cv2?

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I'm using py-tesseract for OCR on images as below but I'm unable to get consistent output from the unprocessed images. How can the spotted background be reduced and the numbers highlighted using cv2 to increase accuracy? I'm also interested in keeping the separators in the output string.

[image: Example]

[image: Example2]

Below pre-processing seems to work with some accuracy

```py
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
    (T, threshInv) = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[image: Example]

Getting output using psm --6: 6.903.722,99

Comment: You could try Hough circle detection and remove detected circles based on their radius (e.g. everything smaller than threshold is set to 0)

Comment: Hough makes no sense here at all.

Comment: you *could* try some closing morphology... but that *could* eat at the digits as well. best to deploy something that simply doesn't care about those dots. any CNN that has learned these digits will simply not care about the dots. it'll just detect the digit and its location and that's it. I'm appalled how OCR still works by hacking the data into tiny pieces and then feeding them into digital brains that could do so much more, if given the whole picture.

Comment: you could try applying a fourier transform, then masking those dots (which form a *grid*) out of the spectrum, then transforming back. you **really** ought to provide better resolution pictures. these are thumbnails, unfit for any processing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I see, thank you for all the input! What seems like a first step is to increase DPI, is that correct? The tiny pieces work for non-spotted background, and I usually don't encounter it, that is why my method has worked thus far! (The size is a bit larger than what was uploaded)

Comment: You could threshold and get contours, then remove all objects smaller than some area. However, that might remove the periods as well.

Comment: You could blur the image then sharpen it like : `cv::GaussianBlur(frame, image, cv::Size(0, 0), 3);` `cv::addWeighted(frame, 1.5, image, -0.5, 0, image);`, you can also look into Laplacian sharpening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution, which is based on the ideas on a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200291/remove-black-header-section-of-image-using-python-opencv/60218663). The main idea is to apply a [Hit-or-Miss](https://theailearner.com/tag/hit-or-miss-transformation-opencv/) operation looking for the pattern you want to eliminate. In this case the pattern is one black (or white, if you invert the image) surrounded by pixels of the complimentary color. I've also included a thresholding operation with some bias, because some of the characters are easily destroyed (you could really benefit from more high-res image). These are the steps:

1. Get **grayscale** image via color conversion
2. **Threshold with bias** to get a binary image
3. Apply the **Hit-or-Miss** with one central pixel target kernel
4. Use the result from the prior operation to **suppress** the noise in the original image

Let's see the code:

```
# Imports:
import numpy as np
import cv2

 image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "8WFNvsZ.jpg"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Convert RGB to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold via Otsu:
thresh, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# Use Otsu's threshold value and add some bias:
thresh = 1.05 * thresh
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV )
```

The first bit of code gets the binary image of the input. Note that I've added some bias to the threshold obtained via Otsu to avoid degrading the characters. This is the result:

[image]

Ok, let's apply the Hit-or-Miss operation to get the *dot mask*:

```
# Perform morphological hit or miss operation
kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,1,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
dotMask = cv2.filter2D(binaryImage, -1, kernel)

# Bitwise-xor mask with binary image to remove dots
result = cv2.bitwise_xor(binaryImage, dotMask)
```

The *dot mask* is this:

[image]

And the result of subtracting (or `XOR`ing) this mask to the original binary image is this:

[image]

If I run the inverted (black text on white background) result image on `PyOCR` I get this string output:

```
Text is: 6.003.722,09
```

The other image produces this final result:

[image]

And its `OCR` returns this:

```
Text is: 4.705.640,00
```

Comment: Thank you for this, stepwise process! Extremely helpful and very accurate!

Comment: I ran some tests and found that the dot mask is not subtracted from the images, and I can't understand why, since I copied your code

Comment: @MisterButter hard to tell you what’s going on without seeing the images. However, if the images are too different from what you originally posted here, some additional tweaking might be necessary. The only parameter to tweak is the bias factor `1.05`. Try small increments or decrements and see what kind of result it yields.

Comment: Thank you for the input, and for the great writeup!